# Is it possible to batch ZKP proofs from different polynomials but same point?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

According to the ZKP MOOC lecture by Dan Boneh, it is possible to batch proofs from different polynomials and different points into a single group element:
[image: Slide from ZKP MOOC lecture]

Nonetheless, I haven't been able to find any protocol that provides this functionality since most of them batch proofs of the same polynomial on different points.

How could that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [PLONK paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf). (I think the original KZG Paper covers only batch opening of a single polynomial at multiple points)

The PLONK paper cover 2 more scenarios as compared to the KZG paper, different Polynomials at the same point & different polynomials at different points.

Page 11

This is the part for different polynomials, same point.

[image: Batched PCS]

"acc" is accepted. If the pairing equation is not satisfied, then the verifier rejects the proof.